# PHP - Doctrine get relations

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a User model with a One-to-Many (Unidirectional with Join Table) relations with Profil

But when I do

```
$user = $userRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('User');
$user = $userRepository->findOneBy(
                array('username' => $username,
                 'password' => $password)
                );
echo $user->getProfils()->getLibelle();
```

or

```
echo $user->getProfils()[0];
```

I have nothing. No errors. No results.
My tables are created and completed.

If I do

```
$user = $userRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('User');
$user = $userRepository->findOneBy(
                array('username' => $username,
                 'password' => $password)
                );
echo $user->getUsername();
```

I have good results.

User.php model

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="users")
 **/

    class User
    {
         /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
        protected $id;

        /** @Column(type="string") **/
        protected $username;

        /** @Column(type="string") **/
        protected $password;

        /** @Column(type="string") **/
        protected $email;

        /**
         * Many User have Many Profils.
         * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Profil")
         * @JoinTable(name="users_profils",
         *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
         *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="profil_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=false)}
         *      )
         */
        private $profils;


        public function __construct()
        {
             $this->profils = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        }


        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        public function getUsername()
        {
            return $this->username;
        }

        public function setUserName($username)
        {
            $this->username = $username;
        }

        public function getPassword()
        {
            return $this->password;
        }

        public function setPassword($password)
        {
            $this->password = $password;
        }

        public function getEmail()
        {
            return $this->email;
        }

        public function setEmail($email)
        {
            $this->email = $email;
        }

        public function getProfils()
        {
            return $this->profils;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Profil.php Model

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="profils")
 **/
class Profil
{
     /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    protected $libelle;

    /** @Column(type="integer") **/
    protected $level;


    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLibelle()
    {
        return $this->libelle;
    }

    public function setLibelle($libelle)
    {
        $this->libelle = $libelle;
    }

    public function getLevel()
    {
        return $this->level;
    }

    public function setLevel($level)
    {
        $this->level = $level;
    }
}
?>
```

Could you tell me what's I'm missing ?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE :
Profil.php:

```
class Profil
{
     /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    protected $libelle;

    /** @Column(type="integer") **/
    protected $level;

    /**
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="profils")
    * @JoinColumn(unique=false)
    */
    private $user;
```

User.php:

```
 /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
protected $id;

/** @Column(type="string") **/
protected $username;

/** @Column(type="string") **/
protected $password;

/** @Column(type="string") **/
protected $email;


/**
* @OneToMany(targetEntity="Profil", mappedBy="user")
*/
private $profils;
```

I tried this:

```
print_r($user->getProfils()->toArray());
```

Result : Array()

Comment: For starters, you have a ManyToMany in your User entity.  And no relation at all in your Profile.  The Symfony docs have some more examples which might help: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html Just drop the @ORM prefix.

Comment: Ok, can you take a look at the new code pls ? thx

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution, if that can help somebody:

Here's the final code.

User.php

```
class User
{
     /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id;

/** @Column(type="string") **/
protected $username;

/** @Column(type="string") **/
protected $password;

/** @Column(type="string") **/
protected $email;


/**
 * Many User have Many Profils.
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Profil")
 * @JoinTable(name="users_profils",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="profil_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=false)}
 *      )
 */
protected $profils;


public function __construct()
{
     $this->profils = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
public function getProfils()
{
    return $this->profils ;
}
```

Profil.php

```
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="profils")
 **/
class Profil
{
     /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    protected $libelle;

    /** @Column(type="integer") **/
    protected $level;

    protected $user;
```

Now we can have all profils from one user.

```
    $userRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('User');
    $user = $userRepository->findOneBy(
        array('username' => $username,
         'password' => $password)
        );
    $profils = $user->getProfils()->toArray();
    foreach($profils as $profil){
        echo $profil->getLibelle() .'<br>';
        echo $profil->getLevel().'<br>';
        echo $profil->getId().'<br>';
    }
```

Edit : The problem was $user->getProfils does not return ONE object
But an array collection.

In first you need to convert this in array with getProfils()->toArray()

Now you can iterate on and call its getter.

```
$profils = $user->getProfils()->toArray();
for($profils as profil){
   $libelle = $profil->getLibelle()
}
```

I have a relation ManyToMany.
So users can have many profils.

Comment: So what was the problem and what is the solution. You don't explain any of this inside your answer, all you do is post a lot of code without any comments. How will that help anyone?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i update the solution. I hope it is more clear.